# Spring AOP with annotations Help Needed !

Tags: logging, annotations, audit, spring-aop, aspects

Can anyone help me with some sample code?

I need to implement Spring AOP and Annotations to achieve a Db Audit or Logging, in a Services Level.

Some code I found online, but nothing very clear and tidy.

I tried it with examples, but I never could get the Interceptors work properly. And I could not run either of Advisors for example @Before or @After.

I've seen in the examples, most using the XML configuration file, but I know that in some cases use may be omitted. How and when?

And finally, it is really necessary and mandatory use of the @ Audit annotation and / or @ Pointcut?

I would greatly appreciate your help. I'm pretty clueless about it,

Thank you so much...
Cheers,

-CaktusJP-

Answer (score 1):

Read Chapter 7 of Spring documentation....
following is the link...
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html

you can find some good tutorials at vaannila.com, weblogs.com also has some spoon feeding tutorials..